# Entity framework assembly issue

Tags: entity-framework-5

When i am try to use bulkinsert method on EF by using entityframework.bulinsert dll getting Error message _"**Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.MappingAPI, Version=5.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ee2e825d201459e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified**".

Answer (score 2):

It simply means the assembly is **missing** in your project AND/OR 'EntityFramework.MappingAPI, Version=5.0.0.6,  is **missing** in your References.

Download the   'EntityFramework.MappingAPI, Version=5.0.0.6, from [***HERE***](https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/)
Extract the dll's from the folder and add a reference to the appropriate one that is version 5, from your solution.

OR

**To install EntityFramework.MappingAPI, run the following command in the Package Manager Console**

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.MappingAPI -Version 5.0.0.6
```

*This will install and automatically add a reference to it.``*

Comment: Old post, but helped me. I would recommend installing the BulkInsert reference from Package Manager (I used NuGet and searched for BulkInsert). This automatically installed the correct MappingAPI dll because it is dependent. When I tried manually downloading and referencing these dll's, the correct MappingAPI version was not available.